# Azure ReservedIPAddress & Cloud Service without an endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a cloud service that opens a socket externally and requires a whitelisted IP address. Nothing will externally initiate a connection with my service.

When I attempt to publish it with an associated ReservedIP address I get the following error: `Validation Errors: Error validating the .cscfg file against the .csdef file. Severity:Error, message:ReservedIP 'xxxx' was not mapped to an endpoint. The service definition must contain atleast one endpoint that maps to the ReservedIP..`

.cscfg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="Gateway" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="5" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <Role name="WorkerRole1">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="yyyyy" />
      <Setting name="APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" value="xxx" />
      <Setting name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="dev" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
  <NetworkConfiguration>
    <AddressAssignments>
      <ReservedIPs>
       <ReservedIP name="xxxxx"/>
      </ReservedIPs>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

1. Is there a way to deploy this without specifying an endpoint? (I'm using VS2017RC to deploy)
2. If not, what would the xml look like for a dummy 'endpoint' and what risks do I run doing that?
3. Is there a better way I should be approaching this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like ReservedIP is only supported with services containing an external endpoint. What you can do is add an external endpoint but firewall it off with the NSG ([Network Security Group](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/network-security-groups/)).

On help defining an endpoint see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-enable-communication-role-instances

Also, if you use a port that is actually not bound to in the machine, it should not be a vulnerability; but adding a deny rule in NSG would cover for any change in future as well.

[Aside] If your service does not have any incoming connections, you should consider using a worker role instead of a web role. Long running threads can get terminated in web role instances.

Comment: Went with the dummy endpoint to be able to fix the ReservedIP. Thanks for your additional information.

Comment: @Prescott, anyone able to put in a result? I am having trouble with this on a Cloud Service (Extended Support) deployment when trying to set a Static IP.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue and the working solution for me was to take the "Input endpoint" from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-enable-communication-role-instances) and place it in .csdef file within the WorkerRole tag.

```
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="StandardWeb" protocol="http" port="80" localPort="80" />
</Endpoints>
```

Comment: Could you please include the code in your answer, just in case the link you referred to changes?